# ajax jquery doesnt work on ie

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hey guys. I'm usign a js/ajax script that doesnt work with internet explorer. Firefox its ok.

Btw the head tag, im using this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Check if url hash value exists (for bookmark)
    $.history.init(pageload);   

    //highlight the selected link
    $('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');

    //Seearch for link with REL set to ajax
    $('a[rel=ajax]').click(function () {

        //grab the full url
        var hash = this.href;

        //remove the # value
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

        //for back button
        $.history.load(hash);   

        //clear the selected class and add the class class to the selected link
        $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        //hide the content and show the progress bar
        $('#content').hide();
        $('#loading').show();

        //run the ajax
        getPage();

        //cancel the anchor tag behaviour
        return false;
    }); 
});


function pageload(hash) {
    //if hash value exists, run the ajax
    if (hash) getPage();    
}

function getPage() {

    //generate the parameter for the php script
    var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://pathfofolder/js/loader.php",   
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {  

            //hide the progress bar
            $('#loading').hide();   

            //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
            $('#content').html(html);

            //display the body with fadeIn transition
            $('#content').fadeIn('slow');       
        }       
    });
}
```

The loader.php contain the php code to get pages, something like:

```
switch($_GET['page'])  {
    case '#link1' : $page = 'contenthere'; break;
} 
echo $page;
```

So, on the links, i'm using Link 1 to load the content into the div  content.

The script does works well with firefox, but with internet explorer it doesnt load the content. Could someone pls help me to fix this?

It not go into the success function at all on IE, and i'm getting no html error from IE too.

Best Regards.

Comment: Are you getting a javascript error in IE?  When you alert the return content is it correct, or does it not go into the success function at all?

Comment: It is not go into the success function at all tandu.

Comment: since you're not registered, you'll lose control of your account any time your browser cookie is deleted. As long as the cookie is active, you'll be able to edit your question and comment on any post on this page.

Comment: Maybe the class setting does not work properly. Check this question, maybe it could help you out some... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527228/ie8-v8-not-changing-class-for-a-dom-element-despite-js-function-changing-the-elem

Comment: Thank you very much. Just add rel="ajax" on line, now its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your html is sounds. FF tends to auto fix the syntax.