# jQuery content replacement within content replacement not working in IE7

Tags: jquery

I'm using .html() to do some relatively simple content replacement on a site with tabbed navigation.  However, I'm running into a problem where a separate content replacement isn't working from within content that has itself been replaced.

I've setup a test here.  In IE7, if you click on the "how it works" tab then click on the little circles at the bottom, the image and the associated quote text just disappear.  Of course, this works perfectly fine in other browsers.

http://stage.slappotown.com/

You can see the js controlling all of this at the top of the page.  However, I had to put the javascript that actually calls the function to replace the quotes in the body, towards the bottom. This might be part of the problem but for some reason when I tried to put that code:

```
jQuery('.quotePicker li a').click(function () {
setQuote(this);
return false;
})
```

in the head as part of the .ready function, then it doesn't work at all.  Any help would be appreciated.

JS fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/maFKQ/4/

I tried moving the click handler for the setQuote function into the head but it doesn't seem to work at all when I do that.

Comment: can we see the code for setQuote?

Comment: @maxedison `function setQuote(f) {
var a = jQuery(f).attr('href');
jQuery('.quoteContainer').html(jQuery(a).html());
jQuery(f).parent().addClass('current');
jQuery('.quotePicker li').not(jQuery(f).parent()).removeClass('current');
} `

Comment: All the code is in the link he posted. I've tested it in jsfiddle and it replicates in IE8 compatibility mode (sort of IE7 mode).

Comment: setting a break point in IE7, it seems that clicking on the selector doesn't seem to actually trigger the setQuote function, even though the selector is correct.  
    jQuery('.quotePicker li a').click(function () {
        setQuote(this);
        return false;
    });

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to this about using addclass and remove class in IE. I've found myself that it is kinda buggy over there (in this case, it was IE8 strict mode but one never knows...)

[IE8 v8 not changing class for a DOM element despite JS function changing the element attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527228/ie8-v8-not-changing-class-for-a-dom-element-despite-js-function-changing-the-ele)