# Class isn't  added on page load

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi I seem to be having some problems with my website at the menu. When I first load the page the first element of the menu should have a class active on IE9 the class active is extended to every element on the menu and on the other browsers the class isn't added at all. If I start clicking on the menu buttons everything start's running normally.

Weird thing is that this only happens on the server if I try loading for example http://www.foxteam.net/ the problem appears but if I load http://www.foxteam.net/index.php the site works normally on all browsers.
This is very confusing for me because from what I know even when you open http://www.foxteam.net/ the browser opens `index.php` file.

What is the problem in my case?

The menu is in the a separate file called `header.php` that is included in `index.php` with include function.

This is the code I have used to create this effect but I doubt it will help because yesterday everything worked fine and today I only worked with the contact page:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
         <li><a href="index.php" class="active">home</a></li>
         <li><a href="about.php">about us</a></li>
         <li><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.php">contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf("/");
            var currentPHP = document.location.href.substr(i+1);
            $("ul#main-menu li a").removeClass('active');
            $("ul#main-menu li a[href^='"+currentPHP+"']").addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: how is your server setup? do you have a index.html file? do you have a .htaccess file?

Comment: This method doesn't allow url parameters with / slashes in them. e.g. http://www.foxteam.net/index.php?x=/about.php  use window.location.href.split('?')[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your page, you are trying to find a link on the page using the page segment of the url.

When you use http://www.foxteam.net/index.php your code is able to pickup the acnhor with href set to 'index.php'. However when you use the url http://www.foxteam.net/ the page segment is blank and hence `$("ul#main-menu li a[href^='"+currentPHP+"']")` is not matching any link.

Replace the current document load script in your page with this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf("/");
        var currentPHP = document.location.href.substr(i+1);
        $("ul#main-menu li a").removeClass('active');
        var link = $("ul#main-menu li a[href^='"+currentPHP+"']");
        if(link.length < 1) {
            link = $("ul#main-menu li a:first");
        }
        link.addClass('active');
});
```

For IE issue: Try this (not tested)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf("/");
        var currentPHP = document.location.href.substr(i+1);
        $("ul#main-menu li a").removeClass('active');
        var link = $("ul#main-menu li a[href^='"+currentPHP+"']");
        if(currentPHP.length < 2 || link.length < 1) {
            link = $("ul#main-menu li a:first");
        }
        link.addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This seems to have solved the problems in most of the browsers except IE9 witch still adds that class active to every element of the menu

Comment: @user985482 Give the updated answer a try... I haven't tested it though

Answer (score 0):

Given the answer I got on this question

[IE8 v8 not changing class for a DOM element despite JS function changing the element attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527228/ie8-v8-not-changing-class-for-a-dom-element-despite-js-function-changing-the-ele)

I guess it's all about toggling instead of adding/removing classes

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using JavaScript to add and remove class, a much better method is to do this on the backed which makes your site more accessible if JavaScript is turned off, this resolve your current link issues as well.

Check out this post [How add class='active' to html menu with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913415/how-add-class-active-to-html-menu-with-php)