# jquery toggleClass not working on IE when changing css attribute but it does when changing input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Need to know if it is possible to find a workaround for this issue on IE9, it does display perfectly on chrome/firefox, the value changes as it is expected but the div will not expand its height.

This code is on an external .js file and I've tried to put it directly in the html to no avail.

Thank you for your help, here's the code:

HTML

```html
<div class="active-collapsed">Some stuff here</div>
```

CSS

```css
.active-collapsed {height:345px;}
.active-expanded {height:690px;}
#exp-btn {margin-bottom:5px;width:80px;}
```

jQuery v1.7.2

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('#exp-btn').click(function () {
        $(".active-collapsed").toggleClass("active-expanded");


        if ($(this).val() == "+ profiles") {
            $(this).val("- profiles");
        } else {
            $(this).val("+ profiles");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: put up your html and css too please.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: a simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4UGck/2/ works with even older versions of jquery.

Comment: I saw the fiddle and puzzles me even more, thank you anyway.

Comment: I did that but probably isn't what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/M3j7T/

Comment: Problem solved. I forgot to put attribute "overflow:hidden;" in class ".active-collapsed ". Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it replicates in IE9, but in IE I found that toggling was not effective when modifying CSS attributes.

[IE8 v8 not changing class for a DOM element despite JS function changing the element attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527228/ie8-v8-not-changing-class-for-a-dom-element-despite-js-function-changing-the-ele)

So, check if this applies to you and change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4UGck/4/ works perfectly fine in IE9. All I did was change val() to text() and added overflow: hidden to your css.

```
$(function(){
    $('#exp-btn').click(function () {
        $(".active-collapsed").toggleClass("active-expanded");


        if ($(this).text() == "+ profiles") {
            $(this).text("- profiles");
        } else {
            $(this).text("+ profiles");
        }
    });

});
```

And the CSS

```
.active-collapsed {height:345px; overflow: hidden;}
```