# Replacing multiple occurrences of text with jQuery in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a table that I need to alter after data binding has happened.  I was doing great until we tested on IE8.  On that browser, it failed.  In essence, a 3rd party control will render as 2 tables.  1st table contains the headers for a grid (including sorting/filtering/grouping options) and the 2nd table contains the data itself.  I have a requirement to "alter" the header, add a "master header" row, augment the classes with some of our own on the TD elements and the A elements.  The whole jQuery function looks like this:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    var grid = $(this).data("tGrid");
    if ($(this)[0].id.indexOf("open") != -1)
        grid = $("#open tbody")[0];
    else
        grid = $("#closed tbody")[0];

    var tb1 = $(grid).html();

    if (tb1.indexOf("<tr><td") == -1 && tb1.indexOf("<TR><TD") == -1 && tb1.indexOf("<TR>\r\n<TD") == -1) {
        // Lower case
        tb1 = tb1.replace(/<th class=/g, "<td class=");
        tb1 = tb1.replace(/th>/g, "td>");

        // Upper case
        tb1 = tb1.replace(/<TH class=/g, "<td class=");
        tb1 = tb1.replace(/TH>/g, "td>");

        $("td.t-header").each(function() {
            var text = $(this).html();
            text = text.replace("t-header", "t-header rr-header rr-header-text");
            $(this).html(text);
        });
        $("a.t-link").each(function () {
            var text = $(this).html();
            text = text.replace("t-link", "t-link rr-link");
            $(this).html(text);
        });

        //tb1 = tb1.replace(/t-header/g, "t-header rr-header rr-header-text");
        //tb1 = tb1.replace(/t-link/g, "t-link rr-link");

        tb1 = tb1.replace("Project ID", "Project<br/>ID");
        tb1 = tb1.replace("Risk ID", "Risk<br/>ID");
        tb1 = tb1.replace("Managing Department", "Managing<br/>Department");
        tb1 = tb1.replace("Cost Impact", "Cost<br/>Impact");
        tb1 = tb1.replace("Schedule Impact", "Schedule<br/>Impact");
        tb1 = tb1.replace("Probability of Occurance", "Probability<br/>of<br/>Occurance");
        tb1 = tb1.replace("Responsible Party", "Responsible<br/>Party");
        tb1 = tb1.replace("Due Date", "Due<br/>Date");
        tb1 = tb1.replace("Cost Severity", "Cost<br/>Severity");
        tb1 = tb1.replace("Schedule Severity", "Schedule<br/>Severity");

        tb1 = "<tr><td colspan='7' class='rr-header rr-risk-identification'>RISK IDENTIFICATION</td>" +
            "<td colspan='3' class='rr-header rr-risk-assessment'>RISK ASSESSMENT</td>" +
            "<td colspan='2' class='rr-header rr-risk-mitigation'>RISK MITIGATION</td>" +
            "<td colspan='2' class='rr-header rr-severity-index'>SEVERITY INDEX</td></tr>" +
            tb1;

        $(grid).html(tb1);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the following code (snippets) to work when run on **IE8**.  So far I've had no luck.  Here is my original code (snippet from above), which works fine in IE9 and above, Chrome, FireFox, etc - but **does not work in IE8**:

```
tb1 = tb1.replace(/t-header/g, "t-header rr-header rr-header-text");
tb1 = tb1.replace(/t-link/g, "t-link rr-link");
```

I've also tried doing this (snippet also from above):

```
$("td.t-header").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    text = text.replace("t-header", "t-header rr-header rr-header-text");
    $(this).html(text);
});
$("a.t-link").each(function () {
    var text = $(this).html();
    text = text.replace("t-link", "t-link rr-link");
    $(this).html(text);
});
```

The results I am getting using a regex replace looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the first TD replaced correctly but all of the remainder did something **weird**!!  Using the EACH loop just plain fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to modify the class list would it be possible just to directly set the class names from inside your each loop?

```
$("td.t-header").each(function() {
    this.className = "t-header rr-header rr-header-text";
});
```

Another solution using Jqueries toggle class is listed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2576780/2511885

Comment: I needed to do a little bit more to make sure I was affecting the exact items but other than that, this is perfect for my needs!